# opencsv does not export attributes of parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, entity, parent, opencsv

I use com.opencsv 4.1 and I want to export an entity class to a csv file.
The problem is that this entity class extends another class. So, when I export it, I get only the fields of the child class.

Below is my code for writting to the csv file:

```
List<ActiveSubstance> activeSubstances = getActiveSubstances();
    File reportFile = new File( "activeSubstances.csv");
    Writer writer = new PrintWriter(reportFile);


    StatefulBeanToCsv<ActiveSubstance> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<ActiveSubstance>(writer)
        .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
        .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
        .build();
    beanToCsv.write(activeSubstances);
    writer.close();
```

The exported file that I get has the below line:

```
 ,,false,xx.model.ActiveSubstanceClass@29f9a8b9
```

My parent class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

  @Id
  @DiffIgnore
  @Column(name = "UUID")
  @CsvBindByName(column = "UUID")
  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
  private String uuid;

  @Column(name = "CODE")
  @CsvBindByName(column = "CODE")
  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
  private String code;

 public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
  }

  public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

My child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ACTIVE_SUBSTANCE")
public class ActiveSubstance extends AbstractEntity {

  @Column(name = "CRITICAL")
  @CsvBindByName(column = "CRITICAL")
  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
  private Boolean critical;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVE_SUBSTANCE_CLASS_ID")
  @CsvBindByName(column = "ACTIVE_SUBSTANCE_CLASS_ID")
  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 4)
  private ActiveSubstanceClass activeSubstanceClass;

/**
   * Default constructor
   */
  public ActiveSubstance() {
  }

  public Boolean getCritical() {
    return critical;
  }

  public void setCritical(Boolean critical) {
    this.critical = critical;
  }

  public ActiveSubstanceClass getActiveSubstanceClass() {
    return activeSubstanceClass;
  }

  public void setActiveSubstanceClass(ActiveSubstanceClass activeSubstanceClass) 
  {
    this.activeSubstanceClass = activeSubstanceClass;
  }
}
```

Why are the parent's attributes not exported? How can I get them? 
Moreover, how can I get the activeSubstanceClass.toString in my csv file and not the object?

I would be really grateful if somebody could help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the fields in the abstract class protected instead of private so they are visible to the child class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using OpenCSV 3.10. I tried using protected fields in a concrete parent class, in short the inherited fields are not exported, details below.

Parent Class:

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByPosition;

public class ParentCsv {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    protected String firstField;

    public String getFirstField() {
        return firstField;
    }

    public void setFirstField(String firstField) {
        this.firstField = firstField;
    }
}
```

Child Class:

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByPosition;

public class ChildCsv extends ParentCsv {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String secondField;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private String thirdField;

    public String getSecondField() {
        return secondField;
    }

    public void setSecondField(String secondField) {
        this.secondField = secondField;
    }

    public String getThirdField() {
        return thirdField;
    }

    public void setThirdField(String thirdField) {
        this.thirdField = thirdField;
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
ChildCsv childCsvToExport = new ChildCsv();
childCsvToExport.setFirstField("firstField");
childCsvToExport.setSecondField("secondField");
childCsvToExport.setThirdField("thirdField");

try {
    Writer writer = new FileWriter("yourfile.csv");
    StatefulBeanToCsv statefulBeanToCsvBuilder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).withQuotechar(Character.MIN_VALUE).withSeparator('|').build();
    statefulBeanToCsvBuilder.write(childCsvToExport);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I obtain:

```
|secondField|thirdField
```